# Find the relation between the dimension of the nullspace of $A$ and $A^t$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a $n \times n$ matrix, what is the relation between the dimension of the nullspace of the homogeneous system of $A$ and the one of $A^t$?

Comment: If you are talking about the nullspaces of the linear maps $x\longmapsto Ax$ and $x\longmapsto A^tx$, it is well-known that these have the same rank. So the nullspaces have the same dimension in this case (since the domains are the same) by the rank-nullity theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** For a given matrix $A$, the dimension of the left null space is equal to the dimension of the right null space.

Comment: By left and right null spaces you mean the parts of the matrix? as $\left ( \text{left null space} | \space\space \text{right null space} \right )$ ?

Comment: @Georgey No, the Left null space is the subspace of $K^n$ (treated as row vectors), such that $lA = 0$. The Right null space is the subspace of $K^n$ (treated as column vectors), such that $Ar = 0 $.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $L:\mathbb F^n\rightarrow \mathbb F^n$ with $L(v)=Av$. Also let $\{e_i\}$ be the natural basis of $\mathbb F^n$.
 
We know that $n=\operatorname{Dim}(\operatorname{Im}(L))+\operatorname{Dim}(\operatorname{Ker}(L))$ (why?)
But $\operatorname{Dim}(\operatorname{Im}(L))=\operatorname{Dim}(\{Ae_1,Ae_2,\ldots,Ae_n\})=\operatorname{Rank}(A)$ (why?) and $\operatorname{Dim}(\operatorname{Ker}(L))$ is the dimension of the nullspace of $A$.

Therefore the dimension of the nullspace of $A$ is $n-\operatorname{Rank}(A)$. Now what do you know about $\operatorname{Rank}(A)$ and $\operatorname{Rank}(A^T)$?